# Bash-Script (separating string)

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, uniq

I have an exercise in which I have to get a string from the user `read str` and to print the number of times which the last character of this string is being repeated.

For example, the string is: `ab2aa2b122`
and the output will be : `4` because `2` is being repeated 4 times in the string.

My problem is to divide the string into single characters. I want that every character will be separated from the other character by space `" "` or by a `\n` in order to use the `tr` command and `uniq` command.

I have to use `uniq` and `sort` commands, in order to use these I have to split the characters, which means that every character must be separated by space or by `\n`.

Comment: Using GNU sed: `sed 's/\B/ /g' <<<"$string"` or `sed 's/\B/\n/g' <<<"$string"` might be a start.

Answer (score 1):

A 100% pure bash solution:

```
read -r -p "Enter your string: " a
l=${a:(-1)}
b=${a//[^$l]/}
n=${#b}
echo "Last character is \`$l' and is repeated $n times in the string \`$a'"
```

No loop, no external process, nothing!

As a one-liner (to show it's really short, and probably the shortest possible!):

```
echo "ab2aa2b122"|{ read -r a;b=${a//[^${a: -1}]/};echo ${#b};}
```

#### Edit

Explanations of the first version (the second one is exactly the same, but suited for a code-golf contest).

- First line line reads user input and stores that input in variable `a`.
- `l=${a:(-1)}` will store the last character of `a` in `l`. More generally, `${a:i:j}` expands to the substring of `a` starting at index *i*, of length *j*. When *i*=-1, it expands to the last character.
- Parameter expansion is used in the next line: `${a//P/R}` will expand to `a` withall the `P`'s replaced by `R`. Here, `R` is empty, and `P` is `[^$l]`, so this matches all characters distinct from `l`. Bottom line: `${a//[^$l]/}` expands to `a` where all the characters different from the last are deleted. So we're left with just `2222` in your case.
- `${#b}` expands to the size of `b` (here, its length). So we're done!

Comment: wow thanks, may you please tell me what's the first solution is doing? It's an extended regular expression solution, right? I would be very thankful if you would explain abit. thanks!

Comment: @user1923376 Added some explanation. I hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you very much! If ill have any more question, may I ask them from you? Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the substitution stuff, really clever

Comment: Sorry, but I have another question.. I may not actually use this way, because, we still didn't learn it (Iv'e just checked), so, I actually have to split all characters as I said in the description up. Which means that every character must be seperated. May you give me a solution for this? (You may just tell how to seperate them)- I actually have to use sort and uniq commands. Again- I apologize, and very thankful to you help!

Comment: @user1923376 skwllsp's answer has a possibility to separate the characters from each other (but it's forking the external process `sed`).

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, they are using sed, and I still didn't learn it.. :(

Comment: @user1923376 Then what have you learnt so far? What are you allowed to use?

Comment: Iv'e learnt basic commands such as cat,cut,tr,sort,uniq,for and while loops,if, cp,wc,input-output (>|),abit of globe style and extended regular expressions (egrep..) but I'm allowed to use egrep and Extended reg expressions, and globe style in the current excercise. Thanks!

Comment: @user1923376 I wrote another answer. Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can use `sed` in your exercise, but with `sed` it can be done like this:

```
bash-3.1$ PPP=`echo ab2aa2b122 | sed 's/\(.\)/\1 /g'`
bash-3.1$ echo $PPP
a b 2 a a 2 b 1 2 2
```

Comment: Iv'e learn basic commands such as cat,cut,tr,sort,uniq,for and while loops,if, cp,wc,input-output (>|),abit of globe style and extended regular expressions (egrep..) but I'm allowed to use egrep and Extended reg expressions, and globe style here, lso no sed..

Answer (score 0):

awk one-liner:

```
kent$  echo "ab2aa2b122"|awk  'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]++;print "last char "$NF" : "a[$NF]" times";}'
last char 2 : 4 times
```

if you just want to get the number "4":

```
kent$  echo "ab2aa2b122"|awk  'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]++;print a[$NF]}'
4
```

Comment: Guys, thanks for all your comments, but I can't use all these ways (Cause I still didn't learn it). I have to use uniq and sort commands, in order to use these- I have to split the characters, which means that every character must be seperated by space or by \n. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the OP:

> My problem is to divide the string into single characters. I want that every character will be seperated from the other character by space (" ") or by a \n (next line)-in order to use the tr command and uniq command.

From a comment left as a comment to my other answer:

> Iv'e learnt basic commands such as cat,cut,tr,sort,uniq,for and while loops,if, cp,wc,input-output (>|),abit of globe style and extended regular expressions (egrep..) but I'm allowed to use egrep and Extended reg expressions, and globe style in the current excercise. Thanks!

To "divide" your string using `grep`:

- Using a terrible `echo`-pipe and subshell:

  ```
  echo "$string" | grep -o '.'
  ```
- Using a here string:

  ```
  grep -o '.' <<< "$string"
  ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not allowed to use grep too... XD

Comment: I'm allowed to use grep too. :( I really apologize for being annoying.. :S but I can't solve it alone. :(

Comment: @user1923376 Ah but you wrote you are allowed to use `egrep`.

Answer (score 0):

**Only** using `wc`, `cut` and `tr`:

```
#/bin/bash

input="ab2aa2b122"

length=$(wc -c <<< $input)

last=$(cut -c $((length-1)) <<< $input)

tr -dc $last <<< $input | wc -c
```

`wc -c` counts the number of characters in the string.

`cut -c $len-1` gets the last character in the string

`tr -dc $last` removes all the characters that aren't the last *(i.e 2)* leaving the string `2222` and then use `wc -c` to count the length again.

```
./script.sh 
4
```

Comment: Same algorithm as my answer `:-)`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf reading the comments hopefully the use of just these commands is okay, I've been racking my brains on how to split a string to separate characters with only the *allowed* tools but I don't think it's possible so `uniq` and `sort` are out the window.